# "Process failed to start: Access denied" whilst attempting to compile PDF

Tags: miktex, windows, texworks

I have just installed TeXworks, and MiKTeX on my home PC to continue work from university. I configured TeXworks to compile using MiKTeX, however once I opened my university work in TeXworks, and attempted to compile it I got the notice: "Process failed to start: Access denied"

How do I give TeXworks permission to use MiKTeX?

Comment: ??? TeXworks is included in MiKTeX. Did you make a separate installation?

Comment: How do I run TeXworks through MiKTeX?

Comment: Ahh, I think I found it. So I uninstalled the version of TeXworks I installed separately, and tried to run the same file, but instead got this message:

Sorry, but C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-pdftex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/decla/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help. @Bernard

Comment: You will have more information in the .log file of the file you try to compile (same name, same directory). In case you do not find any useful information, try to run pdflatex from the command line.

Comment: 1.  Close texworks.  2. run texify junk from a command line, where junk is some random file name which need not exist.  3. Everything should work now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.